# Why are camera files typically prefixed "DSCN" or something similar?

Tags: images, photos, file-format

I've noticed that files from my digital camera are always saved on the SD card as `DSCN####.JPG`. Some other cameras also save with this naming scheme, but others yet save with the prefix `DSC`, and sometimes even other strings. Is there any significance to these prefixes? Does it mean anything to the computer when importing the photos? And why do different cameras use different prefixes?

Comment: To anyone itching to migrate this to photography or close it as off-topic: this question is about how the camera _interfaces with the computer_ and _saves its files for the computer to use_; therefore, it is on-topic per the SU FAQ.

Comment: )  is it a nikon camera ? all cameras use some prefix naming for all image files , i believe only nikon uses this one

Comment: very good question, +1 - I've always wondered this myself...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSC) says, `DSC` stands for *Digital Still Camera*. Would make sense then.

Your camera is a Nikon, and `DSCN` stands for [Digital Still Capture - Nikon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSCN).

So the `C` is either *Camera* or *Capture*.

Answer (score 4):

["Digital Still Camera - Nikon"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikon#Digital_single_lens_reflex_cameras)

Answer (score 3):

Most cameras follow the [Design rule for Camera File systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_rule_for_camera_file_system), a specification that defines the directory structure, file format and naming pattern (among other things) of camera storage.

From the linked Wikipedia article:

> The filesystem in a digital camera contains a DCIM (Digital Camera
>   IMages) directory which can contain multiple subdirectories with
>   names such as "123ABCDE", which consist of a unique directory number
>   (in the range 100…999) and five alphanumeric characters, which may be
>   freely chosen and often refer to a camera maker. These directories
>   contain files with names such as "ABCD1234.JPG", which consist of four
>   alphanumeric characters (often "DSC_", "DSC0" or "IMG_"), followed by
>   a number.

As stated, manufacturers can chose to customize the first four characters of image files' names; Canon cameras, for example, prefix their files with `IMG_`, while Nikon cameras have the `DSC_` or `DSCN` prefix.